# In the described game, can the rubies be divided into 105 piles of one?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

### Problem

In a pirate ship, there is a chest with 3 sacks containing 5, 49, and 51 rubies respectively. The treasurer of the pirate ship is bored and decides to play a game with the following rules:

- He can merge any two piles together into one pile, and
- he can divide a pile with an even number of rubies into two piles of equal size.

He makes one move every day, and he will finish the game when he has divided the rubies into 105 piles of one. Is it possible for him to finish the game?

### Solution attempt

It seems to me that it's not possible to finish the game, and here is the argument that I could come up with:

Assume, for the sake of reaching a contradiction, that a state with 105 piles of 1 can be reached.

The start state has no piles of 1, so the piles of 1 must have been obtained from other piles. From the rules, the only way of obtaining a pile of 1 from other piles is by splitting a pile of 2 into two piles of 1. So, each two piles of 1 must have originated from splitting a pile of 2. The resulting number of piles of 1 generated this way is even, because every pile of 2 generates 2 piles of 1. However, there is an odd number (105) of piles of 1, so this state is impossible to from the given start state using the defined rules.

Is this correct, or at least on the right track?

Comment: Suppose you started with a pile a $2$ and a pile of $3$.  Your argument would again apply and show that we can't end up with $\{1,1,1,1,1\}$, yes?  But we could have $\{2,3\}\mapsto \{1,1,3\}\mapsto \{1,4\}\mapsto \{1,2,2\}\mapsto \{1,1,1,2\}\mapsto \{1,1,1,1,1\}$, no?

Comment: Minor note:  $5+49+41=95$.  If you took this problem from [these notes](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.042/spring17/mcs.pdf) then the $41$ you wrote was meant to be a $51$.

Comment: @lulu - Oops, you're right. Thank you. Fixed that in the post.

Comment: @lulu - That counterexample is a good point. So, my argument doesn't work.

Comment: "The resulting number of piles of 1 generated this way is even, because every pile of 2 generates 2 piles of 1. "  Except... you can combine one of the piles of $1$ with *another* pile to get rid of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As lulu mentioned in a comment, your proof is incorrect.

The reason for this is that you assume that the only way the number of piles of $1$ can be modified is by dividing a pile of $2$ into two piles of $1$, and saying that since this preserves parity $105$ piles is unreachable.

However, what you have failed to take into account is that the number of piles of $1$ can also *decrease*: you can merge a pile of $1$ with another pile not of size $1$, decreasing the number of piles of size $1$ by $1$, or even merge two piles of size $1$ (although there would not be any good reason to do so).

With regards to the actual solution, I would recommend the following tactic: think about what your first move can be, and what that results in. Obviously it has to be a pile merge. I'll give you a head start: if you start by merging the $5$ and $51$, then all pile sizes are divisible by $7$, and this does not change through either merges or splits. Can you finish from here?

Comment: Wow, this is really cool! Mod-bashing with 3 different prime moduli, one for each case ... I've never seen a problem like this

Comment: Is it just a coincidence that $105 = 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7$? I wonder which initial conditions on piles allow eventual splitting into all $1$-size piles. I suspect it's a very difficult problem, in general  ...

Comment: It is not a coincidence. For an argument like this to be possible, we need it to be the case that, after an initial merge, all the pile sizes are divisible by some $k$ coprime to $2$; this clearly implies that the sum of pile sizes (which is an invariant) is also divisible by $k$. The three smallest possible such $k$ are clearly $3$, $5$, and $7$; since all of these must divide the sum of pile sizes, the smallest possible sum of pile sizes is $105$. (In other words, neither the choice of $3$, $5$ and $7$ nor the choice of $105$ is coincidental.)

Comment: The three numbers $a$, $b$, $c$ (in the original problem, $5$, $49$, $51$) have to satisfy 

$$\gcd(a+b,c) \neq 1$$ and $$\gcd(a+c,b) \neq 1$$ and $$\gcd(b+c,a) \neq 1$$

Comment: Thank you, I was able to finish it just from the head start that you gave, without looking at the other answers. Afterwards, I saw that it became similar to what David G. Spork posted in the answer below.

Answer (score 5):

All initial piles are odd, so your first move must be one of three mergings:

- If you merge $5 + 49$, your two resulting piles ($54$ and $51$) are each divisible by $3$.  Your two legal operations retain this property for each pile, so you can never finish.
- If you instead merge $5 + 51$, your two resulting piles ($56$ and $49$) are each divisible by $7$.  Your two legal operations retain this property for each pile, so you can never finish.
- If you instead merge $49 + 51$, your two resulting piles ($5$ and $100$) are each divisible by $5$.  Your two legal operations retain this property for each pile, so you can never finish.

Hence:  You can never finish.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee:  I just solved the general problem, and will post such a question within the hour.